# Cannot kill conda in ubuntu

Tags: python, anaconda, ubuntu-18.04

There is an instance of conda running in my ubuntu. I type kill [process ID] it does not kill that process. I tried also killall but does not work too. What should I do? My ubuntu version is 18.04.

Comment: Try killall -10 conda

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work

Comment: Do you have a python script running in the background which is forcing conda to run?

Comment: I guess so, but I am not sure.

Comment: Well in that case, try to find it and see if it's non critical. Then try killing it or disabling it. You may have changed some /etc file which has caused unexpected behaviour in the system so google that too.